# How do I change which email address GitHub uses for my Gravatar image?

Tags: github, gravatar

GitHub currently uses my private email for Gravatar, but I would like it to use one of my work ones instead. However, I can't find any way to change which email address is used to get the image.

I have successfully added the email address to my account, and the avatar shows next to it in the list of my account emails. I can log in using either email address and my account password, but regardless of which email I use when I log in, the default one is used for the avatar next to all my actions.

Ideally, I'd like a way to switch between the avatars on different places of GitHub (for example, to use the private one on my profile, and the work one on all my commits to the work project), but being able to change which is used on my current actions is good enough. (Heck, as a starting point, even being able to change it at all is good enough...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got it almost right, you'll have to add the other email to your [profile settings](https://github.com/settings/emails). However, Github picks up the first listed email address for your gravatar.

So you'll have to remove the email ids such that the preferred gravatar email id bubbles up. Once done, you can re-add the removed email ids.

Comment: OK - this means that there's no way I can use different avatars on different parts of Github, right? Also, it means that there's no easier way to switch avatar than to remove and re-add my email address... Sigh...

Comment: @TomasLycken unfortunately, yes that